# Sharepoint Development without Windows Server

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, windows-server

Short question: **Can I develop for Microsoft Sharepoint, using Visual Studio, without using a Windows server machine?**

I'm trying to do work for a Sharepoint site that requires me making custom web parts but from what I've read, I won't be able to develop in visual studio without having Sharepoint installed. As well, I can't install Sharepoint without running a Microsoft Server OS.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12950548/sharepoint-2010-development-without-local-server-installation) is a link to a similar question asked from a couple years ago. I would love to know if there have been any fixes since then.

I am running Windows 7, and Visual Studio 2013. I don't think that the version of VS really matters, since the equivalent Sharepoint version is available for free.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for SharePoint 2010, then you can install it on Windows 7 or 8 but with a modification http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(office.14).aspx, For SharePoint 2013 you need to have Windows server

To setup SharePoint 2010 on Windows 7 or 8 machine:

1. Copy the SharePointFoundation.exe (or setup.exe) installation file to a folder on the computer where you are installing SharePoint and doing your development, such as in the following path:

> c:\SharePointFiles

2. Extract the installation files by opening a Command Prompt window, and then typing the following command at the directory location of the folder where you copied the installation files in the previous step.

   For SharePoint Foundation 2010:

> c:\SharePointFiles\SharePoint /extract:c:\SharePointFiles

For SharePoint Server 2010:

> c:\SharePointFiles\OfficeServer /extract:c:\SharePointFiles

3. Using a text editor such as Notepad, open the installation configuration file, config.xml, located in the following path:

> c:\SharePointFiles\files\Setup\config.xml

4. Add this line inside the  tag:

> `<Setting Id="AllowWindowsClientInstall" Value="True"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Sharepoint Foundation or install sharepoint server. But, if you wanna do this you have to remove the sharepoint check SO check on the setup.

[Install sharepoint in windows 7](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/7756b081-f8c3-47de-9200-8b8a49bb76c3/how-to-install-sharepoint-server-2010-in-window-7-professional-64-bit-machine?forum=sharepointgeneral)